# Issue in validation pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have written validation pattern like

```
        function checkValid(str)
        {
            var isPattern = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\/]\d{4}$/.test(str);
            if (!isPattern)
                return false;
            var d = new Date(str);
            return (!isNaN(d));
        }

       in the code 
          ...
          ....
          else if(!checkValid(newstartdate))
            {
                swal({
                    title: "",
                    text: "Please enter valid start date! "
                });
            }
            else if(!checkValid(newenddate))
            {
                swal({
                    title: "",
                    text: "Please enter valid end date! "
                });
            }
```

I have to follow proper dd/mm/yyyy format and the above line is not accepting the date like "22/12/2026".

Comment: `pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/[0-9]{4}"` you can try this pattern

Comment: I think you meant `[21]` instead of `[31]`. Also what about October?

Comment: `[\/\/]` should just be `\/`. No need to put it twice in a character class.

Comment: First capture group is allowing 1-9 (with or without 0 prefix), 10-19, and 30-39: nothing in the 20-29 range. Second one allows 1-9 (with or without 0 prefix), 11, or 12: missing 10. Last date segment requires any 4 digits. You can also just include a single "\/" without a character class containing two of them.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern:

```js
var isPattern = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;
console.log(isPattern.test("22/12/2026"));
console.log(isPattern.test("32/14/2026"));
console.log(isPattern.test("31/02/2026"));
console.log(isPattern.test("29/02/1996"));
```

Will consider leap years as well.

Look [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1410702.aspx) for explantation.

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @Bergi changed the answer and referenced the source.

Comment: Why so complicated? Also this doesn't really help the OP to understand what he did wrong.

Comment: @user2179026 check now

Comment: I have updated my question... Please help me now where i m wrong

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date_regex =  /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$/;
alert(date_regex.test("22/12/1993"));
```

Comment: That doesn't look like dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: How? can you please explain me?

Comment: he want "22/12/2026" like this bro

Comment: I think yours is mm/dd/yyyy rather than dd/mm/yyyy. The first capture group wouldn't allow "22".

Comment: @Bergi and Poosh sorry for bad argument brothers...
answer updated! thanks for correcting me:-)